# how to add projects on bottom of side bar and retrieve on demand like Komodo IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS code and I am not sure if I can have that feature like Komodo IDE provides in Vscode . Here is the [image of that feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNvCX.png) I'd like to have:

Comment: Why use VSC if it looks and behaves just like Komodo, If Komodo does what you want use Komodo, Have you looked at **Multi Root Workspace**

Comment: thank you... but it is not exactly what I want... What I'd like is to have a selected project on the top, while maintaining the workspace at the bottom.